# Animate position absolute jquery doesn't work properly.

Tags: jquery, animation

I've got little problem. I made some jQuery code 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uHgmr
but when I add this to the dev version of website it doesn't work properly.

http://mateusz.digitalzone.pl/kalendarz-szkolen/
(click "Stwórz pakiet" and next icon in left bottom corner).

Anybody know how to fix it? ﻿

Comment: Do you have jquery UI loaded on your website?

Comment: Ok. I change code that imgclone is attend to body, not ".o-szkoleniu" and this look fine. That doesn't work the way I want, but I haven't got time.

Answer (score 0):

Add this and it should work. Your using .filter

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation works for me, but check your console (in chrome press shift & control + j)

You have a error here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listaSzkolenKoszyk.length; i++) {
```

Where `listaSzkolenKoszyk` is undefined therefore having no length

Comment: Animation work, but not the way I want. I want to start animate with place I click, but it's starting from bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try two things.

First, make sure that when you reference the "this" pointer, it is in the proper context. In this case, "this" points to the jQuery object retrieved by `$('.awesome-animation')`.

Second, try placing the animation that sets the image's opacity to 0 inside of the first animation's callback function, so that the opacity gets animated after the first animation is complete. Like this:

```
$('.awesome-animation').on('click', function () {
    var cart = $('.o-szkoleniu');

    // 1.
    // Make sure that "this" is in the right context
    // In this case, "this" points to the jQuery element corresponding to
    // $('.awesome-animation') and .find() will find elements within
    // this context.
    var imgtodrag = $(this).find("img.single-training-cover").eq(0);
    var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone();

    // ...

    imgclone.animate({
        'top': cart.offset().top,
        'left': cart.offset().left,
        'width': 112,
        'height': 167
    }, 1000, 'easeOutCirc', function() {

        imgclone.css('position', 'absolute');

        // 2.
        // This function should go in here, so that it gets executed AFTER
        // the position has been animated.
        imgclone.animate({
            'opacity' : 0
        },  function () {
            $(this).detach()
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think "this" is in the right context. Animation should start in the position where I click.